# Double slash gets added to the URL when clicking on chat navigation

Tags: discussion, bug, chat, navigation

Whenever I click on the link that is on the sidebar (which shows the chatrooms) an extra slash is added always in the URL before `rooms`, e.g.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com//rooms/41570

The link is not broken - and goes to the room regardless.

Here's a highlighted screenshot. Should this be ignored or fixed?

[image]

[image]

**Edit :** Attached the hand drawn circles of the screenshot as requested on comments by few.

Comment: It doesn't even redirect when you follow that link. It is a no-impact corner case.

Comment: Did this _really_ warrant a post on meta? There is literally no problem here.

Comment: "...literally no problem here." ... The accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523318/is-a-url-with-in-the-path-section-valid summarizes it as "yes, it is valid, no, don't use it". Browser and cookie behavior can be unexpected when faced with a double slash. I'm not saying it is significant problem, but it is probably not the behavior that the designer desired.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Not for the average user, no. But advanced users may be running userscripts that get borked by this. It's probably a minor effort to get fixed and it may even be the symptom of a much larger problem that we don't see yet. TL;DR: we can't say if it's worth fixing the bug, but it's a bug, so we mention it and see what the team says. If they stamp a [meta-tag:status-wont-fix] on it, that's a reply too.

Comment: Okay, let's add some of that context into the question then, summarising the _actual, tangible problems_ that are your concern here.

Comment: @Mast Yeah, that's the point. It's not a showstopper while surfing the site. But it may affect in some complex scenario

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings as I know, sometimes Spring Boot complains about double slashes.

Comment: "It doesn't even redirect when you follow that link" - Curious, I see a 301 redirect and the double slash is removed? @rene

Comment: @MrWhite interesting, it does indeed when you click to the room, but not for the users.

Comment: Related, almost certainly duplicate, on MSE: [URL of Meta Stack Exchange chat room transcript (which I opened from inbox) contains 2 slashes after "chat.meta.stackexchange.com". Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355147/289905).

Comment: _Aside:_ Is there a _magic_ way to get those chat links to appear in the sidebar? It seems to be completely random for me? Currently I can't get the chat links/section to appear at all in the sidebar?

Comment: @MrWhite Not sure about how it works. But [go here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403070/3282633) and you can find it in the right sidebar..

Comment: @Mast Yes, Exactly your point is the one that's in my mind